# Factorize condition with ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to factorize this line with a ruby operator like ||= or something else ? :

```
if sheet.rows[start[:y]] then row = sheet.rows[start[:y]] else row = sheet.add_row [] end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ternary operator:

```
row = sheet.rows[start[:y]] ? sheet.rows[start[:y]] : sheet.add_row([])
```

Alternatively:

```
row = sheet.rows[start[:y]]
row = sheet.add_row [] if !row
```

Or (thanks to @tight):

```
row = sheet.rows[start[:y]] || sheet.add_row([])
```

Comment: The ternary operator throw me an error and I have no log on my company environement so I can't use it

Comment: Ok in fact I just need to add parenthesis around my add_row condition. Thx !

Comment: Or just use `row = sheet.rows[start[:y]] || sheet.add_row([])`